# How to animate a QGraphicsGridLayout?

Tags: qt, animation, graphics

I have a QGraphicsGridLayout with a number of QGraphicsLayoutItems.  I would like to collapse i.e. shrink the QGraphicsGridLayout when clicking one of the QGraphicsGrid items.  It seems like I should be using the QPropertyAnimate function, but this only works for QObjects.  Does anyone know the solution to this issue?  W

Comment: QVariantAnimiations operate on QObjects not QGraphicLayoutItems.  If QVariantAnimation is possible can you show an example?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the example?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the example.  The documentation while robust doesn't have nice examples like this so thank you for taking the time to do this!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything which could be moved, resized, recolored and so on, regardless of whether it is a subclass of *QObject* or not, could be animated using [QVariantAnimation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html). I have tested it without problems with [QStandardItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html) (as in [this example of mine](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-CustomList)) and [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html).

The trick is to act upon a `valueChanged` signal and do whatever you wanna do with the animated object. `const QVariant &value` gives you the current value of the animation, so if you've set for example the start and end values to 0 and 100 respectively and write something like `my_rect->setPos(value.toInt(), my_rect.y())` in the callback function, you will move a rectangle `my_rect` horizontally from position (0, y) to (100, y).

As for the case with *QGraphicsGridLayout*, you should manipulate the *QGraphicsWidget* object it is set to. Here is an example of an animated horizontal shrink of the entire grid layout when the button is pressed:

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class QPushButton;
class QGraphicsWidget;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QPushButton *m_button;
    QGraphicsWidget *m_form;

private slots:
    void onButtonClicked();
    void onValueChanged(const QVariant &value);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QVariantAnimation>
#include <QGraphicsGridLayout>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    m_button(new QPushButton(tr("Shrink me"))),
    m_form(new QGraphicsWidget())
{
    auto *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    auto *layout = new QGraphicsGridLayout();

    view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));

    layout->addItem(view->scene()->addWidget(new QTextEdit()), 0, 0);
    layout->addItem(view->scene()->addWidget(m_button), 0, 1);

    m_form->setLayout(layout);

    view->scene()->addItem(m_form);

    setCentralWidget(view);
    resize(800, 600);

    connect(m_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onButtonClicked);
}

void MainWindow::onButtonClicked()
{
    auto *animation = new QVariantAnimation(this);

    m_button->setDisabled(true);

    animation->setStartValue(m_form->geometry().width());
    animation->setEndValue(0.0);
    animation->setDuration(1500);

    connect(animation, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged, this, &MainWindow::onValueChanged);

    animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}

void MainWindow::onValueChanged(const QVariant &value)
{
    m_form->resize(value.toDouble(), m_form->geometry().height());
}
```

Probably this code doesn't solve your entire problem, which is by the way hard to be understood completely, because of the lack of a code example and detailed description. However it answers the question in the title and could serve as a good starting point for you to experiment further.